# Tee - mimicking program only writes the initial input to file, ignoring all sequential inputs

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

So I have a mytee program (with much much less functionality). Trying to learn how to work with pipes / children / etc

(1) I do pipe
(2) Create the file(s)
(3) fork
(4) the parent does scanf to get the text
(5) sends the text to the pipe
(6) child receives it and writes it to files

-> #4 should be a loop until the user writes '.'
-> #6 should continue writing new lines, but somewhere there is a breakdown.

Some of the things that I think it might be:
1. Something is wrong with my permissions (but O_APPEND is there, and not sure what else I would need)
2. there may be a problem in parent do while loop, where it should send the msg to the pipe (fd[1])
3. #6 where I strongly think my problem lies. After the initial write it doesn, continue writing. I am not sure if I need to somehow keep track of the size of bytes already written, but if that was the case I would expect the last message to be there not the first.

I'm pretty much at a loss right now

I run it using

```
   ./mytee test1
```

Code:

```
ret = pipe (fd);
  if (ret == -1)
  {
    perror ("pipe");
    return 1;
  }
  for (i=0;i<argc-1;i++) {
     if ((filefd[i] = open(argv[i+1], O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND, 0644)) < 0) {
                perror(argv[i]);        /* open failed */
                return 1;
     }
  }
  pid = fork();
  if (pid==0)     /* child */
  {
   int read_data;
   do {
     read_data = read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
     for(i=0;i<argc;i++) {
       write(filefd[i], buffer, read_data);
     }

   } while (read_data > 1);
  for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
    close(filefd[i]);
  return 0;
  }
  else {          /* parent */
    char msg[20];
    do{
      scanf("%s",msg);
      write(fd[1],msg,sizeof(msg));
    }while (strcmp(msg,".")!=0);
    while ((pid = wait(&status)) != -1)
       fprintf(stderr, "process %d exits with %d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    return 0;
  }
```

Adding Output:

```
$ ./a.out test1
qwe
asd
zxc
.
^C
```

It doesn't exit properly. I think the child is stuck in the loop
And the contents of test1:

```
qwe
```

Comment: It works OK for me (on ubuntu), modulo the fact that input lines shorter than 20 bytes result in NULs and leftover characters from the previously-read line in the output files because the parent writes 20 bytes unconditionally. Can you provide sample input and output files that show the problem you're having?

Comment: Doesn't `tee` simply read `stdin` and write anything read to both `stdout` and a file until eof is reached? I think your program does something different. Also since you tagged the question "linux", are you aware that there exist two syscalls (`tee` and `splice`) that are explicitly made for that purpose?

Comment: @Damon It's a a somewhat similar program to tee in functionality, it's definitely not a full functioning tee. It just takes a scanf message one at a time and writes it to all files specified. I did hear about splice, but this one is more of I need to figure out how this stuff works, I am having problems understanding what is going wrong here.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I am not sure why it's writing 20 bytes unconditionally - I had similar problem before where it wrote in chunks of 1024 byteI switched to write(filefd[i], buffer, read_data); from write(filefd[i], buffer, sizeof(buffer));

Comment: With `write(fd[1],msg,sizeof(msg));`, the expression `sizeof(msg)` is constant. It'll always be 20 if msg is declared as `char msg[20]`, regardless of the data that msg contains.

Comment: well that shouldn't be a problem - I'm ok with some extra spaces, it wouldn't prevent me from writing subsequent messages right?

Comment: It's writing NULs and characters that were previously written, since msg is never zeroed out. If you type `first line` and then `2nd`, what gets written out the second time is is `2nd\0t line\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`. Subsequent messages do get written out, but programs that read the output files may not show everything if they are confused by the presence of NULs.

Comment: Doh you're right! that's the problem! This is what's actually in the text file asd^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@qwe^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@xzc^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
. Now I got it to qwe^@y^@asd^@y^@zxc^@y^@, but it still puts the null character at the end. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you Mark, that solved it. I changed it to write(fd[1], msg, strlen(msg)) and voila! If you want to post that as the answer I will mark it as accepted :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working through this with the OP, reportedly the problem was unconditionally writing all 20 bytes of `msg` instead of just the NUL-terminated string contained within it. Suggested minimal fix: change

```
scanf("%s",msg);
write(fd[1],msg,sizeof(msg));
```

to

```
scanf("%19s",msg);
write(fd[1],msg,strlen(msg));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues, which could potentially cause that behaviour.

Firstly, your loop condition doesn't look right.  Currently it will terminate if a single byte is read.  Change it to this:

```
while (read_data > 0);
```

The other issue I see is that you're writing to more files than you opened.  Make sure you loop to `argc-1`, not `argc`:

```
for (i=0; i<argc-1; i++)
```

Comment: I changed both of those - it has no effect. The main for loop did have i<argc-1 which is the one that actually does anything to the files